# vb.net menu strip shadow remains after viewing

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

I am using a MenuStrip in my application like this:

```
Private top_menu As New MenuStrip
Private menu_item_file As New ToolStripMenuItem("File")
```

and I add items to the menu like this:

```
 With top_menu
    .Items.Add(menu_item_file)
 End With

 With menu_item_file
    .DropDownItems.Add(sub_menu_item_show_all)
    .DropDownItems.Add(sub_menu_item_show_reg)
 End With
```

The menu drops down and it has a shadow (by default). It works fine in Windows7, but when I test it in XP, the shadow remains after the user moves away from the menu (or clicks the item). I can't figure out what is causing this. The menu continues to work fine and drops down every time the user hovers over it, but the shadow never goes away. The menu does drop down over an existing panel which has a picture in it, but I don't think that is causing this behavior.

Comment: You can test if it's the picture panel causing it by moving it aside and testing it again to see if the issue still occurs without the panel in the way.

Comment: It does it without the picture panel there as well.

Comment: Do you have this picture in the panel using standard properties, or are you overriding the `Panel`'s paint events/methods?

Comment: its all standard stuff, no overriding of anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's some kind of bug in Win XP. Only appears when you have set your picture to your bacground. Cured by turning off shadows in Win XP.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19277/Let-Your-Form-Drop-a-Shadow